# How to clear all textboxs in a DIV using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have some asp textboxs in a div container. I just want to clear those when i am clicking the  CLEAR button.

I say common class 'text' for all textboxes
and then wrote this jQuery

```
$(".text").text("");
```

It's not working ..

How to do this ?
I need the most efficient code .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('a.clearButton').bind('click', function() {
    $('#divId input').val('');
});
```

Notes:

1. You should use **val**() instead of text().
2. You are asking for efficient code - and using **class selector is not efficient**.

   Either use id, or add tag name.

Comment: just a note.. it will remove the values of the button if anything present inside '#divId'

Answer (score 13):

If you need to clear text boxes values alone, you can change the code like this:

```
$("#divID").find("input[type=text]").val('');
```

or

```
$("#divID").find("input:text").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourcontainerid input:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work successfully

```
$(':text').val("");
```

Comment: Please use the edit link below your answer and use its "code formatting" feature to clearly distinguish your machine code/text from your answer text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ClearButton').bind('click',function(){
$('#div1').Find('input[type=text]').val('');
});

or

$('#ClearButton').bind('click',function(){
$('#div1').Find('input:text').val('');
});
```