# Resetting textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, reset

I'm working on a project for school and I'm stuck on how to reset all the textboxs on the page. This is what my reset button looks like:

```
 <form name="Reset">
  <input type="button" value="New ordering sheet." onClick="Reset()">
 </form>
```

I don't know what to do for the function, I have no code for the Reset() function:

```
 function Reset() {}
```

Comment: I would try something like setting for every textbox.value = "" or something like that? Try to come up with something. You are at school you should try harder. If we just tell you the answer you won't know how to do it on your own... this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477543/how-do-i-assign-value-to-a-textbox-using-javascript

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Comment: Do you need custom "resetting"? If not just `<input type="reset" value="New ordering sheet."/>`

Comment: It looks like there actually is a reset function for forms already as @nevermind sends the link so :D.. use Google before you ask next time!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following questions, there are a few ways of doing it in them:

[How to clear all textboxs in a DIV using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346934/how-to-clear-all-textboxs-in-a-div-using-jquery)

[JQuery how to clear all the input:textfields of a .class on a form. Not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054377/jquery-how-to-clear-all-the-inputtextfields-of-a-class-on-a-form-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help!! just have a 'reset' input inside your form :-)

```
<form name="myform" action="http://something" method="POST">
 <input type="text" size="25" value="Enter your name here!">
 <input type="submit" value="Send me your name!">
 <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
</form>
```